I have no idea why setTimeout wrapping promise not working as i expected
I have this code.


const testArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const test = async () => {
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        console.log("Testing console log: ", new Date());
    });
};

const testPromises = testArray.map(async (value) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)).then(() => test())
);

const testResult = testPromises.reduce(
    (p, testPromise) => p.then(() => testPromise),
    Promise.resolve()
);



So i expected resolve promises made with testArray map function sequentially with setTimeout worked and log the messsage with 2 seconds interval.
but it is logging at the same time.
I have no idea why this is not working.

You'd need to move setTimeout() into the reduce. Right now, you create an array of promises that all resolve in 2 seconds; they've already started ticking from the moment you create them

The issue is with your testPromises. It creates 5 promises that resolve after 2 seconds simultaneously upon the declaration. When they are declared, the setTimeout countdowns are already ticking.
const testPromises = testArray.map(async (value) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)).then(() => test())
);

[Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]

What you actually want is to create functions that return a Promise using the map function, so the countdown only ticks when it is called.
const testPromises = testArray.map((value) =>
    () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)).then(() => test())
);

[() => Promise, () => Promise, () => Promise, () => Promise, () => Promise]

and then call that function to create the Promise in the reduce sequence:
const testResult = testPromises.reduce(
    (p, testPromise) => p.then(() => testPromise()),
    Promise.resolve()
);

Here's the full code:


const testArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// no need to use async when it returns a Promise explicitly
const test = () => {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log("Testing console log: ", new Date());
  });
};

// map into a funtion that returns a Promise instead
const testPromises = testArray.map((value) =>
  () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)).then(() => test())
);


// when chaining on the Promise using reduce function, call the testPromise() function to create the Promise that resolves after 2 seconds on the fly
const testResult = testPromises.reduce(
  (p, testPromise) => p.then(() => testPromise()),
  Promise.resolve()
);




Oh i got it. I missed that one.
I really appreciate it. : -)

Or just drop the map altogether and move the work int the reduce
